# Convert one list to the other list type

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am doing this below - any better way to do this? converting one list to the other without creating new object?

```
DataContext c = new DataContext();
List<X> x=
context.X.Where(a => a.date>Datetime.Now>).ToList();            
        foreach(var a in x)
        {
            Y y= new Y();
            y.Name= a.Name;                
            c.Ys.InsertOnSubmit(y);
        }

        c.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Can't tell where `b` is coming from. Maybe you mean `x`?

Comment: If you don't need a specific type you could use an Anonymous Type
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Comment: You should use meaningful variable names, not just one letter names.  Let auto-complete handle the typing.  You shouldn't be developing in notepad anymore.

Comment: sorry for snafu. corrected post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try:

```
var ys = context.X
                .Where(x => x.date > DateTime.Now)
                .Select(x => new Y { Name = x.Name });

c.Ys.InsertAllOnSubmit(ys);
```

Comment: +1 very cool! My thoughts exactly but didn't think about `InsertAllOnSubmit` :)

Comment: This will not result in ""Explicit construction of entity type '#some type#' in query is not allowed""?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much shortening would make it *better*. Maybe this would help:

You project into a list of `Y` so you don't have to create new `Y`'s in your loop.

```
List<Y> list_of_ys =
context.X.Where(a => a.date>Datetime.Now)
         .Select(s => new Y(){Name=s.Name})
         .ToList()

foreach(var y in list_of_ys)
{        
   c.Ys.InsertOnSubmit(y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public IList<IPoint> Points
{
    get
    {
        return points.ConvertAll<IPoint>(
            delegate(RandomPoint point)
            {
                return point;
            });
    }   

}
```

If you have an interface and its implementation, for example, then you can use the ConvertAll method as in the example above, where IPoint is an interface and RandomPoint is a class derived from that interface.